# Using decltype for templated function declaration results in "conflict" when defining the templated function

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, using, decltype

I am using a `decltype` to ensure a template function `force2` has the same parameter and return types as another template function `force1` but it doesn't compile. I require the functions to be templated.
Consider this code:

```cpp
template <typename N>
void force1(N a);

template <typename N>
using ForceType = decltype(force1<N>);

template <typename N>
ForceType<N> force2;

template <typename N>
void force2(N a)
{}
```

This results in an error:

```
<source>:11:16: error: 'template<class N> void force2(N)' conflicts with a previous declaration
   11 | void force2(N a)
      |                ^
<source>:8:14: note: previous declaration 'template<class N> ForceType<N> force2<N>'
    8 | ForceType<N> force2;
      |              ^~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

I expected this to compile: with `force2` being a templated function with empty body. What is actually going on over here? The compiler hints that `template<class N> void force2(N)` is not the same as `template<class N> ForceType<N> force2<N>` which I am not able to understand. They definitely seem different on the first look but shouldn't the expansion of `ForceType<N>` result in `template<class N> void force2(N)`?

When I use a concrete type in declaration of `force2`:

```cpp
template <typename N>
void force1(N a);

template <typename N>
using ForceType = decltype(force1<N>);

ForceType<int> force2;

void force2(int a)
{}
```

It compiles without errors.

Comment: You can't declare a variable template and a function template with the same name. In the second example, you have a function forward declaration and a function definition.

Comment: I went through https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template as I had never heard of variable templates before. I still can't see how `template <typename N> ForceType<N> force2;` is a variable template. Doesn't `force2` in this declaration have the type of a function?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `force2` is not a variable template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ForceType<N>` is a dependent type.

[[temp.spec.general]p8](https://wg21.link/temp.spec.general#8):

> If a function declaration acquired its function type through a dependent type without using the syntactic form of a function declarator, the program is ill-formed.

`ForceType<N> force2;` does not meet this requirement, so this is ill-formed.

In compilers, this will be parsed as a variable template since, because of the above rule, it cannot be a function template.

Any attempt to actually use `force2<N>` will result in an error (https://godbolt.org/z/f3Ke3x8db)

---

And even if you were to fix it by making it of the form of a function declaration:

```cpp
template<typename>
struct unary_fn;
template<typename Ret, typename Arg>
struct unary_fn<Ret(Arg)> { using return_type = Ret; using argument_type = Arg; };

template <typename N>
void force1(N a);

template <typename N>
using ForceType = typename unary_fn<decltype(force1<N>)>::return_type(typename unary_fn<decltype(force1<N>)>::argument_type);

template <typename N>
ForceType<N> force2;

template <typename N>
void force2(N a)
{}
```

This would declare two separate templates overloads because `ForceType<N>` and `void(N)` are not equivalent (i.e., the latter is not a definition of the former)

Comment: Even in the latter case you still haven't used "the syntactic form of a function declarator" so it's still ill-formed. But it's also true, as you point out, that a dependent `decltype` is inequivalent to anything other than itself for declaration matching purposes. https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.type#4

Comment: @BrianBi From [[temp.alias\]p2](https://wg21.link/temp.alias#2), `ForceType<N> force2` is equivalent to `typename unary_fn<decltype(force1<N>)>::return_type force2(typename unary_fn<decltype(force1<N>)>::argument_type)`, which does have the required form (you would have to write that in the definition, where you might as well not have a separate declaration)

Comment: It's "equivalent to" what you get by substituting into the alias template definition, but the equivalence is not syntactic. It can't be syntactic, because `F x;` (where `F` is an alias to a function type) is equivalent to `R x(...);`, meaning that the `F` before the `x` expands into something that goes both before and after the `x`. Plus, I don't think substitution into templates is ever syntactic.

Comment: @Artyer "This would declare two separate templates overloads because `ForceType<N>` and `void(N)` are not equivalent". I don't understand this, at least from the function signature POV it appears to me that they are equivalent. However I don't know if there is some other templating concept at work here. If there is something, could you please refer some newbie friendly resource which explain it?

Comment: @Sin3point14 There's a list over here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading but I wouldn't worry too much about it. Basically the redeclaration needs to look exactly the same except the template parameters can be renamed (`template<class T> void f(T)` and `template<class U> void f(U)` are redeclarations). Also, with `ForceType<N>`, the types could be different if you add a function overload of `force1` with different types for the same template parameter and also the `N` is not deducible like in `void(N)`.

Comment: Also, "In compilers, this will be parsed as a variable template" -- I can now see how `ForceType<N> force2;` is ill formed, but how is this a legal variable template? Specifically how can `ForceType<N>` be interpreted as one. Out of curiosity, we can instantiate variables from variable templates, so, is there some way to instantiate variables using `force2`?

Comment: @Sin3point14 I don't think there is a way for `ForceType<N>` to not be a function type. But that doesn't mean a compiler knows that (it might even be undecidable for certain constructs). That would make it ill-formed NDR ( https://wg21.link/temp.res.general#6.1 ), which allows the compiler the liberty to just treat all template declarations as variable templates unless it uses "the syntactic form of a function declarator"

Comment: @Artyer it should always be decidable for deducible type templates, which `ForceType<N>` is

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I meant decidable if something is always a function type/never an object type if it's not in the right syntactic form

Comment: Yes, I understood that. When you have a deducible type template, the compiler should theoretically have everything necessary to determine that in constant time. In this case the decltype names an instantiation of a function template, so it's always a function type.

Answer (score 0):

In the `using ForceType` template declaration, `decltype(force1<N>)` is `void(N a)`. So `ForceType<int> force2;` is the same as declaring `void force2(int a)`, which is simply a function, not a function template.

Now, in `template <typename N> void force2(N a) {}`, you are trying to declare a template with the name `force2`, which is already "used" by the previous declaration.

Note that in the second example, `void force2(int a) {}` is the definition of the function, not conflicting with the `force2` declaration.